# Python code to insert the local timestamp (date + hour)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would you modify the following Python code to insert the local timestamp of the PC where the code is running?

```
entry["serverTimeStamp"] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use `datetime.datetime.now()`; also the `strftime` call might be unneeded depending on the library you use to connect to MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using the pymongo library (MongoClient). Is the strftime necessary in this case?

Comment: No, it's not - see [docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/datetimes.html?highlight=datetimes).

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing with the pytz library.

```
import pytz

entry["serverTimeStamp"] = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Try replacing 'US/Eastern' with your preferred time zone to see if that helps. You can see here all the available time zones for pytz:
https://gist.github.com/heyalexej/8bf688fd67d7199be4a1682b3eec7568